# Closing an already open website that is opened several times

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I have an application that cannot be modified. This application opens a php site that send some info and redirects you to a new site.

It is something like this:

```
<?php
do_something();
save_parameters();
redirectto_website();
?>
```

Now this application calls perhaps 30 times the browser. I only need obviously one redirect.

This was my idea:

```
    <?php
    do_something();
    save_parameters();
if(isset($_SESSION["hello"])){ 
echo    "<script>";
echo   "function realClose()";
echo    "{";
echo      "var win = window.open('','_self'); /* url = '' or 'about:blank'; target='_self' */";
echo    "win.close();";
 echo   "}";
echo    "</script>";
echo "<script>window.onload = realClose()</script>";
}
$_SESSION["hello"] = 1;
redirectto_website();
?>
```

For somewhat reason, this only works in Internet Explorer, even though this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
   function realClose()
    {
      var win = window.open("","_self"); /* url = "" or "about:blank"; target="_self" */
        win.close();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="realClose()">
    </body>
```

Also works with Safari and Chrome. Is there any other way to check if a site is already open? Any suggestions?